# Executing Typescript Jasmine tests via Webpack (Terminal) to test Angular2

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, angular, webpack

Currently I'm trying to get Jasmine to run along with Webpack, to execute tests written in typescript to test Angular2 Apps in the Terminal.

I researched yesterday which packages are available for testing, and while angular2 has *their own approach* ***1**, I looked for other tools than the recommended `jasmine-core` or jasmines native package `jasmine`.

I found `jasmine-node` which is outdated for 2 years now. Currently investigating the *Webpack+Angular2 with Jasmine testing package* ***2**

After reading *Become a Ninja with Angular2* ***3** by Ninja Squad I have no satisfying information on how to combine the 3~5 toolchains.

**Getting to Run Jasmine with Webpack**

Then i started to ignore typescript, to at least get jasmine and webpack get to work together. I found the *Jasmine Webpack Plugin* ***4** and started to follow the instructions.

Currently I'm stuck with getting to work webpack to execute Jasmine.
I added another entry point:

```
entry: {
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.ts', // our angular app
    'test': './src/spec.ts' // Testing with jasmine
},
```

I added the JasmineWebpackPlugin:

```
plugins.push(new jasmineWebpackPlugin());
```

Now I try to combine my setting *with the settings from the angular webpack starter pack* ***5**

I only get errors, can't build anymore.

**Errors in npm-debug.log**

```
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
```

**Additional Infos**

Node Version: 5.5.0

npm: 3.3.12

OS: Windows 7 64-Bit

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "node.extend": "^1.1.3",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "tsconfig-lint": "^0.4.3",
    "tslint": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "typings": "^0.6.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1",
    "webpack-war-archiver-plugin": "0.0.1"
  },
```

Thank you a lot for your time in advance. I do my best to wrap my head around all these new tools, especially webpack/jasmine.

```
    > webpack-dev-server --config webpack-test-config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --inline --debug

 70% 1/1 build modules node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:72
                        var elements = request.replace(/^-?!+/, "").replace(/!!+/g, "!").split("!");
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:72:26
    at node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:28:4
    at node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:159:3
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:75:69)
    at NormalModuleFactory.create (node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:144:8)
    at node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:214:11
    at node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:181:20
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:233:13)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:209:22)
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:185:8)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "jasmine"<
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! jasmine: `webpack-dev-server --config webpack-test-config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --inline --debug`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Can't post more than 2 Links, so I'm listing the links here.

***1**: angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/jasmine-testing-101.html

***2**: angularclass.github.io/angular2-webpack-starter/

***3**: books.ninja-squad.com/angular2

***4**: github.com/iredelmeier/jasmine-webpack-plugin

***5**: github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/webpack.test.config.js

Comment: check this for putting tests to work with webpack -> https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: I already tried that config, but it doesn't look like it is working:

Answer (score 0):

I was taking a look at the angular2 - webpack starter kit again.
It worked after I created an extra file for the tests and copied the spec-bundle.js, which is very important!

Another thing that I had to learn is, that jasmine alone won't do it. Karma is the tool that manages all the tasks that are needed in order to start the testing.

Including:
Setting up PhantomJS, 
directing webpack to compile typescript files
launching istanbul
executing jasmine

Comment: Is there a chance to put your results on github? I would be interested in participating as I'm looking for similar configuration for Ionic2 as it also uses angular2/typescript/webpack

Comment: Hi there! 
I'll put it up as soon as I find some time. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can watch https://github.com/martinmuzatko. 
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Actually I've started to try doing sth similar. I think that simple webpack plugin to execute karma server should be enough. And now I'm facing some not directly related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597719/log4js-and-winston-loggers-conflicting-when-trying-to-run-karma-from-ionic-cli

Answer (score 0):

Seems like NormalModuleFactory.js:72 error is related to dashes in the webpack config filename. Replacing them with dots should solve the problem.